# React Hook Form Fields Calculation

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I Have Form with the Above Fields
1-Charge Amount Default Value =120
2-Charge Count Default Value=1
3-Total Amount =Charge Amount * Charge Count
4-Paid Amount
5-Balance =Total Amount - Paid Amount

[codesandbox] https://codesandbox.io/s/little-dust-s7v9k8?file=/src/MyForm/MyForm.tsx

I Have Tried the Above Code But Paid Amount and Balance not working
 also when submitting the form the Paid amount and total amount become zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `useEffect` and calculate the final values based on the input as below :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const calculate = () => {
      console.log("calculate");
      const amount = values.paidAmount;
      const balance =
        values.chargeAmount * values.chargeCount - parseFloat(amount || "0");
      if (balance !== values.balance) {
        setValue("balance", balance);
      }
    };
    calculate();
  }, [values, setValue]);
```

Example :  [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-forked-fjj9ic?file=/src/MyForm/MyForm.tsx:769-1125)